# Using touchend event within a function for Javascript calculations on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following basic HTML form that includes some range and number inputs. There is some basic JS that takes the inputs, does some calculations and then outputs the results within a div.

This works fine on desktop, but I am having trouble using the touchend (or any touch events) to track when a mobile user changes the inputs. It only updates the calculations when the user moved to another field:

```js
window.onload = function() {
   document.repaymentcalc.deposit.onkeyup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onkeyup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onkeyup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.finalpayment.onkeyup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onkeyup = repayment;

   document.repaymentcalc.deposit.onmouseup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onmouseup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onmouseup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.finalpayment.onmouseup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onmouseup = repayment;

   document.repaymentcalc.deposit.ontouchmove = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.ontouchmove = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.ontouchmove = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.finalpayment.ontouchmove = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.ontouchmove = repayment;

 };

 function repayment() {
   var pv = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10) - parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.deposit.value, 10);
   var d = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.deposit.value, 10);
   var i = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.value, 10) / 1200;
   var n = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
   var fv = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.finalpayment.value, 10);
   var repayment = ( pv - (fv / Math.pow((1 + i), n))) / ((1 - (1 / Math.pow((1 + i), n))) / i);
   var tcost = ( repayment * n ) + fv + d;
   var year = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10);

   document.getElementById("years").innerHTML = year + ' years';
   document.getElementById("repayments").innerHTML = 'Monthly Repayment: £' + repayment.toFixed(0);
   document.getElementById("totalcost").innerHTML = 'Total Cost: £' + tcost.toFixed(0);

 }
```

```css
<style>
h2 {background-color: tomato; padding: 2vw; min-width:400px; width: 35vw; margin:auto; font-family: verdana; font-size: 24px; box-shadow: 2px 2px silver;}
form {background-color: tomato; padding: 2vw; min-width:400px; width: 35vw; margin:auto; font-family: verdana; font-size: 20px; box-shadow: 2px 2px silver;}
input {padding: 0.25vw; width: 25%; font-family: verdana; margin:10px; font-size: 18px;}
</style>
```

```html
<body>

<h2>PCP Loan Calculator</h2>

<br>

<form name="repaymentcalc">

    Deposit £<br>
    <input type="number" step="100" id="deposit" value="500" min="0"><br><br>

    Loan Amount £<br>
    <input type="number" step="100" id="loanamount" value="20000" min="100"><br><br>

    Interest Rate<br>
    <input type="number" step="0.1" id="interestrate" value="4.5" min="0.1" max="49.9">%<br><br>

    Final Payment £<br>
    <input type="number" step="100" id="finalpayment" value="10000" min="0"><br><br>

    Term<br>
    <input type="range" step="0.5" id="numberpayments" value="3" min="1" max="5"><div id="years">3 years</div><br><br>

    <div id="repayments">Monthly Repayment: £320</div><br><br>

    <div id="totalcost">Total Cost: £22023</div>

</form>

</body>
```

Is there another event that would achieve this, or do I need to move to a solution that includes a button click to trigger the calculation?

Comment: You tried `onchange()`?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. That does solve the problem and will accept answer, but it actually made me realise that it wasn't really the issue. The issue is actually that you can't click the up/down arrow next to a 'number' input on a touchscreen. I guess I will have to incorporate +/- buttons instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {

   document.repaymentcalc.deposit.onchange = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onchange = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.finalpayment.onchange = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = repayment;

   document.repaymentcalc.deposit.onkeyup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onkeyup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onkeyup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.finalpayment.onkeyup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onkeyup = repayment;

   document.repaymentcalc.deposit.onmouseup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onmouseup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onmouseup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.finalpayment.onmouseup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onmouseup = repayment;

   document.repaymentcalc.deposit.ontouchmove = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.ontouchmove = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.ontouchmove = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.finalpayment.ontouchmove = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.ontouchmove = repayment;

 };

 function repayment() {
   var pv = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10) - parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.deposit.value, 10);
   var d = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.deposit.value, 10);
   var i = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.value, 10) / 1200;
   var n = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
   var fv = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.finalpayment.value, 10);
   var repayment = ( pv - (fv / Math.pow((1 + i), n))) / ((1 - (1 / Math.pow((1 + i), n))) / i);
   var tcost = ( repayment * n ) + fv + d;
   var year = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10);

   document.getElementById("years").innerHTML = year + ' years';
   document.getElementById("repayments").innerHTML = 'Monthly Repayment: £' + repayment.toFixed(0);
   document.getElementById("totalcost").innerHTML = 'Total Cost: £' + tcost.toFixed(0);

 }
```

```css
<style>
h2 {background-color: tomato; padding: 2vw; min-width:400px; width: 35vw; margin:auto; font-family: verdana; font-size: 24px; box-shadow: 2px 2px silver;}
form {background-color: tomato; padding: 2vw; min-width:400px; width: 35vw; margin:auto; font-family: verdana; font-size: 20px; box-shadow: 2px 2px silver;}
input {padding: 0.25vw; width: 25%; font-family: verdana; margin:10px; font-size: 18px;}
</style>
```

```html
<body>

<h2>PCP Loan Calculator</h2>

<br>

<form name="repaymentcalc">

    Deposit £<br>
    <input type="number" step="100" id="deposit" value="500" min="0"><br><br>

    Loan Amount £<br>
    <input type="number" step="100" id="loanamount" value="20000" min="100"><br><br>

    Interest Rate<br>
    <input type="number" step="0.1" id="interestrate" value="4.5" min="0.1" max="49.9">%<br><br>

    Final Payment £<br>
    <input type="number" step="100" id="finalpayment" value="10000" min="0"><br><br>

    Term<br>
    <input type="range" step="0.5" id="numberpayments" value="3" min="1" max="5"><div id="years">3 years</div><br><br>

    <div id="repayments">Monthly Repayment: £320</div><br><br>

    <div id="totalcost">Total Cost: £22023</div>

</form>

</body>
```